# npm install as a build step in TeamCity

Tags: node.js, teamcity, npm-install

I am studying a TeamCity project which has to do with a .NET application with Angular at the frontend. What it does not make sense to me is I cannot find anywhere `npm install`. For example: [image]

The thing is in case I add a dependency in `package.json` which requires update of `node_modules` folder, everything works fine as far as the artifacts are concerned and Angular finds the files it needs!!
***But how node_modules folder on TeamCity is updated?***
Sorry, for being a little bit abstract; honestly, I cannot find `npm install` anywhere.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I cannot find npm install". The command appears to be the first line in your runner. If you mean where is `npm install` located, well `npm` is a tool installed with Node.JS and `install` is just a parameter. The package.json indicates which packages to pull and the `.npmrc` config file with NPM will indicate where the repositories and credentials to pull from are.

Comment: Hi,   
  i suppose you should install npm on your agent manually ( or schedule updates directly on agent ). Then you should just call npm run build --prod during build. -g parameter in install says global , so you probably need elevated administration rights ,which agent does not have and process might end with no result

Comment: Same issue I'm also facing with Team city

any resolutions?

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend looking at the TeamCity Node Plugin available at https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node.  The plugin, which is also available via the TeamCity Plugin repository for an integrated installer, will allow you to use NVM to install a specific version of Node as well as run NPM to install other dependencies, etc.

I hope this helps!